# Rails 3: Will_paginate's .paginate doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm using newes Rails 3 version with will_paginate.

`@videos = user.youtube_videos.sort.paginate :page => page`

I also added the `@@per_page` attribute to my youtube_video-model.

But it just won't paginate it. I get always all items in the collection listed.

What have I done wrong?

Yours, Joern.

Comment: This is not enough info to help you. Where does `page` in `:page => page` come from? Also I don't think it is a good idea to use `sort` here. If you want to sort your database records you'd better use `:order => ...`.

Comment: page = setup_page(params[:page]) | => | if !arg1.nil? then return arg1.to_i else return 1 end | where arg1 is params[:page]

Comment: Use the '~> 3.0.pre4' version of will_paginate gem. Then assign the per_page like this: `YoutubeVideo.per_page = 10`. It should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution, my own answer, for all other's having trouble with will_paginate and reading this issue:

Create an ApplicationController method like this:

```
def paginate_collection(collection, page, per_page)
  page_results = WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page, collection.length) do |pager|
    pager.replace(collection)
  end
  collection = collection[(page - 1) * per_page, per_page]
  yield collection, page_results
end
```

Then in your Controller, where you got the collection that should be paginated:

```
page = setup_page(params[:page]) # see below
@messages = Message.inbox(account)
paginate_collection(@messages, page, Message.per_page) do |collection, page_results|
  @messages = collection
  @page_results = page_results
end
```

And in your View:

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <%# iterate and show message titles or whatever %>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @page_results %>
```

---

To get the `page` variable defined, check this:

```
def setup_page(page)
  if !page.nil?
    page.to_i
  else
    1
  end
end
```

So `page = setup_page(params[:page])` does the trick, with that simple method.

---

This WORKS!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling `sort` here? That seems unnecessary, and probably would result in it finding all videos and calling pagination on that rather than paying any attention to any variable defined in your `Video` model. Instead, move the sorting logic into the `Video` model by using a scope or use the `order` method.

Comment: I done so, but it didn't help anyways... instead of sort and include Comparable, I just made a new Model Instance Method called "all_for_user" so: YoutubeVideo.all_for_user(user).paginate :page => page ... but without success, same issue

Comment: @Joern: Why are you even doing that? Doesn't YoutubeVideo's table have a `user_id` column on it and therefore you would be able to do `user.youtube_videos` or something of the like?

Comment: this was what I first did, which didn't work with paginate too. This way I also would need to sort it... I like creating my own methods more, here I can explicitly define what should happen.

Comment: sadly, the admin deleted my own answer, but acutally I solved it with `WillPaginate::Collection.create(...)`

Comment: Bryan @ 2nd commentary of all comments: that's what I did with `has_many` first, as you mentioned I need this with the `:order` param set. Only thing that's somewhat less elegant is that I place it in the `YoutubeVideo` Model